# Problema Laravel excel import fecha 1970-01-01

Tags: php, laravel, excel

Buen dia, tengo este problema al importar un archivo excel , con la libreria matwebsite.
el problema es que si el archivo excel no tiene una fecha en la columna "fecha_actualizacion"
toma como valor automaticamente en la bd 1970-01-01, y quisiera que no se guardara ese valor ,que se quedara vacio o nulo.

import (solo anexo ese campo)

```
return new ImportOperCont([
'ImportFechaReal'=>Carbon::instance(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['fecha_actualizacion'])),
]);
```

Comment: Está poniendo por defecto `0`. Pasa que el unix timestamp cero equivale al 1 de enero de 1970 a las 00:00. Habría que buscar cómo validar si es cero para entregar una cadena vacía, etc.

Comment: intenta con un ternario, si es cero que envie null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verifico si la variable row esta vacia, si lo esta envio null, si no envió la fecha que esta en el excel

```
(empty($row['fecha_actualizacion'])) ? 'ImportFechaReal'== null : 'ImportFechaReal'=> Carbon::instance(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['fecha_actualizacion'])),
```